# Trying to Understanding structs. Reference by a List<>

Tags: c#, .net, list, struct

I have the following code:

```
public void Start()
    {
        List<StructCustomer> listCustomer = new List<StructCustomer>();

        listCustomer.Add(
            new StructCustomer { ID = 0, name = "Any Default Name", birthday = DateTime.Now });


        DoSomethingWithStructList(listCustomer);
        StructCustomer customer = listCustomer.First();
        Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}, Name = {1}", customer.ID, customer.name); // Writes ID = 0, Name = "Any Default Name"

    }

public void DoSomethingWithStructList(List<StructCustomer> listStructs)
        {
            StructCustomer test = listStructs.First();
            test.ID = 2;
            test.name = "Edited by method";
            Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}, Name = {1}", test.ID, test.name); // Writes "ID = 2, Name = Edited by method"
        }

 public struct StructCustomer
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public DateTime birthday { get; set; }
        }
```

As you can notice, the variable List is a reference to a List of Customer. Shouldnt the value be edited in the StructCustomer Variable in the List?

I know Structs are value and not reference types, but i am boxing it in a List!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you do this:

```
StructCustomer test = listStructs.First();
test.ID = 2;
test.name = "Edited by method";
Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}, Name = {1}", test.ID, test.name);
```

you are actualy creating a copy of the first struct in the listStructs, so, you'll change the values of the copy, not the real one. Try doing this instead - it should works:

```
listStructs.First().ID = 2;
listStructs.First().name = "Edited by method";
```

So, thats it ;)
OBS: This approach is not recomended by CPU usage, but, its a way out =)

Answer (score 1):

Structs are value types, and as such, when you retrieve them from the list, as in your example, what you are retrieving is a copy of its value. Which you then modify. This does not change anything in the original that is contained in the list.

If you want to make changes to the element in the list, do it like this:

```
listStructs[0].ID = 2;
listStrings[0].name = "Edited by method";
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a list of a structure type will cause each item of the list to encapsulate all of the fields within the structure.  The list's indexed 'get' method will copy all of the fields associated with a list item to the corresponding fields of the return value; the indexed 'put' will copy all of the fields from the passed-in item to the corresponding fields associated with the appropriate list item.  Note that neither the 'get' nor the 'put' creates any attachment between the item in the list and the item which is read or written; future changes to one will not affect the other.

For many kinds of programs, this kind of detachment will sometimes be desirable and sometimes not.  To help facilitate such cases, I would suggest creating a type like:

```
class SimpleHolder<T> { public T Value; /* A field, not a property! */ }
```

and then using a `List<SimpleHolder<StructCustomer>>`.

Your class should create every `SimpleHolder<StructCustomer>` instance itself, and never expose references to any of those instances to outside code.  If you want to have a method, e.g. return item 0, use:

```
StructCustomer FirstCustomer()
{ 
  return listStructHolders[0].Value;
}
```

To store a passed-in value:

```
void AddCustomer(StructCustomer newCustomer)
{
  var temp = new SimpleHolder<StructCustomer>();
  temp.Value = newCustomer;
  listStructHolders.Add(temp);
}
```

To modify the name of customer 3:

```
listStructHolder[3].Value.name = "Fred";
```

Using a simple "exposed-field holder" class will make it easy to combine the advantages of structure types and mutable classes.

Answer (score 0):

The List contains value types, so it returns a values when you ask it for an item. Try making a List and you'll see the same behavior.

As a result, you need to make assignments directly to the list item inside the list. You can have behavior semantically closer to what you are trying to do by iterating over the list in a foreach loop.